# Filename to text

Tags: math-mode

I have several code files I want to include in my appendix in the following format:

```
Appendix X                          filename
--------------------------------------------
filecontents
```

With an appropriate listing in the contents.

So far I have this:

```
\newcommand\codefile[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
  \lhead{Appendix \thesubsection}%
  \rhead{#1}%
  \lstinputlisting{../../src/#1}}
```

My only problem is the right header. If the filename contains an underscore then my compiler (rubber) is assuming I have accidentally omitted the $ and is inserting them. Making the filename have incorrect subscript.

Is there a way I can say "dont automatically insert math mode here"?

Comment: Does package `grffile` help? By the way, please always post complete examples, one can copy paste and compile. This makes testing (and providing a solution) easier for us.

Comment: use `\path{#1}` in the toc and the headline (from `url` package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still get the messages saying missing $ but it doesn't make the filename have subscript in it!

Comment: It's not possible to debug code we can't see, please edit the question so your example is complete from \documentclass to \end{document}

Answer (score 2):

I merely applied `\detokenize` to the argument of `\rhead`, so as to make the underscore a catcode 12.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,listings}
\newcommand\codefile[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
  \lhead{Appendix \thesubsection}%
  \rhead{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \lstinputlisting{#1}}
\begin{document}
\codefile{j_unk.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]